# Is there a better way to say "the break down of 70 minutes is:"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms

In the following sentence, is there a better way to say "*the break down of 70 minutes is*"

> In total, participants will spend 70 minutes in this study; **the break down of 70 minutes is:**
>   10 minutes for [x],
>   20 minutes for [y] and
>   40 minutes for [z]

Comment: I would just leave it out and put "In total, participants will spend 70 minutes in this study: 10 minutes for x, 20 minutes for y, and 40 minutes for z." It is obvious from the context that this is a breakdown.

Comment: The word *breakdown* is widely used by the accountancy profession on both sides of the Atlantic to describe the division of something into its components. One talks about *the sales breakdown*, or the *breakdown of expenses* etc. It would certainly not be out of place in the context you suggest. Though personally I might have said something like: *it breaks down into ten and twenty-minute components as follows:*

Comment: *Of those 70 minutes*?

Comment: Replace your bold text with:  "with the following break-down." .. .  Make sure you include the total number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakdown has many synonyms and with respect to its context in the statement, consider the following options:
Split or divide. Also the sentence could be rephrased as, "In this study, participants will spend a total of 70 minutes, which will be split/divided as followed:" to be more efficient.